# JfreeChart XYAreaChart draw shape at each point

Tags: jfreechart

I want to draw shape at each `XYPoint` in `XYAreaChart`. Kindly suggest me how can i add shaped at each point.

I tried using following option but still not able to draw shape:

```
 XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
 XYAreaRenderer renderer=   (XYAreaRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
 renderer.setOutline(true);
 renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0, true);
 renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(1, true);
 renderer.setSeriesShape(1, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(.5f));
 renderer.setSeriesShape(0, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(.5f));
 renderer.setBaseShape(ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(.5f));
 renderer.setBaseSeriesVisible(true);
 renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.decode("#34C0F1"));
 renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, Color.DARK_GRAY);
 renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.decode("#EBEBEB"));
 renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#B4DEED"));
```

Still unable to get result.

Comment: Object names highlighted as code.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117263).